# how to add export option(pdf and excel) in yajra datatable

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

I want to add export option for pdf and excel.
installed package:
"yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons": "^4.13",
"yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~9.0"

In Controller

$logs = AttendanceRecord::with(['user', 'visitor', 'authVehicle', 'idCard.verifiedBy', 'vehicle.verifiedBy'])->latest();

```
    return DataTables::of($logs)
        ->rawColumns(['action'])
        ->editColumn('auth_type', function ($logs) use ($authTypes) {
            return $authTypes[$logs->auth_type]['name'];
        })
         ->parameters([
            'dom'          => 'Bfrtip',
             'buttons'      => ['excel', 'csv'],
         ])
        ->make(true);

In blade



 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                dataTable(jQuery('#access-logs-table'), url, [
                        { data: 'index', defaultContent: '' },
                        { data: 'auth_type', name: 'auth_type' },
                    ],
                    jQuery('#header-buttons').html()
                );
            });
```

i have got error

Method Yajra\DataTables\EloquentDataTable::parameters does not exist.

how to resolve this